# Qt #include <user_header> gives file not found

Tags: c++, qt

Background - I am trying to selectively include code from another codebase without copying it into my project and changing it. I am using Qt Creator 3.2.1 opensource based on 5.3.2 running on Mac (Clang 5.0 Apple).

In one header file there are the following lines

```
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include "Blob.h"
```

and the compiler complains that type_traits is not found.

The include path in the .pro file points to the folder that contains type_traits.h

I do not really want to copy code from that codebase unless I **REALLY** have to.

Can anybody suggest something that I could do to get it to work?

---- Details added ----

I have created a simple project that includes "RippleAddress.h" from the Ripple/Stellar Codebase (https://github.com/stellar/stellard)

This codebase includes a library called Beast which contains type_traits.h

The Ripple project and Beast are built with SConstruct but I can't see how that helps.

I am trying to avoid making a copy of the files (in order to change the headers) but would prefer to use them as they are.

--- contents of .pro file

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = Test
TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += "/users/daveappleton/Documents/stellard/src/ripple_data/protocol"
INCLUDEPATH += "/users/daveappleton/Documents/stellard/src/beast/beast/cxx14"

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h\
        /users/daveappleton/Documents/stellard/src/beast/beast/cxx14/type_traits.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

I have tried a number of variations on this.

Comment: Did you try `#include <type_traits.h>` instead?

Comment: Those files you include are [C++ standard library header files](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header), that means if you are including them from somewhere else then you have already copied them. Why would you even want to use standard library files if they're not from the standard library?

Comment: I guess it cannot be the problem that you have no CONFIG += c++11. Can you provide an SSCCE? Btw, I think you mean QtCreator 3.2.1. Also, is the include path appearing in the compilation command? Either way, this is insufficient information provided to analyse the problem. Last nitpick is that it is Qt, not QT. See the tagwiki for details.

Comment: joachim
I know that 
    #include "type_traits.h" works - I tested it in my main file.

Since the codebase is contained in another project and I do not want to copy masses of files I was trying to use them in situ.

@lpapp 
I have tried CONFIG += c++11. No diff.
Blame the QT instead of Qt on digital dyslexia. :-/

I will edit the question to add details.